# PostgreSQL driver for Rebol?

Tags: database, postgresql, networking, rebol, rebol3

I am looking at doing some work with Rebol3 and PostgreSQL and trying to plan my approach.  It looks like I have the following options:

1. ODBC access.
2. Write my own driver
3. Maybe there is an existing one that would work.

ODBC access looks like the simplest way forward, but the native PostgreSQL drivers offer some features that are not available there that I would prefer to use.  This leads me to writing my own driver or trying to use the old pure rebol driver from 2003.

A lot of rebol 2 code does not work on rebol 3 and so I would assume that the PostgreSQL driver would require some effort to make work at all, and some more effort to use the more recent protocols for PostgreSQL.  I am guessing this will not be too hard?

My goal is to create some frameworks for quickly and easily tying stored procedures to the front end, to bring some of the better features of some of the rest of my work to Rebol applications.  What do folks think is the best way forward here?

Comment: please drop us a note if you find a way or rewrite the driver for v3. ty.

Comment: I have decided to try to rewrite for v3.  My plan is to try to get the (protocol v2 driver) ported as is to v3, and then to rewrite again for the current PostgreSQL v3 protocol.

Comment: the main issue is that the Rebol2 driver used sync tcp, and Rebol3 uses async tcp with a different port model.  I have also worked on a JDBC bridge but I guess that's little different from using ODBC?

Comment: Thanks.  I am still working on dissecting the rebol2 driver and porting to rebol3.  Unfortunately it is one of three side projects for me right now and it is taking time to get right.  This feedback is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no Rebol 3 PostgresSQL driver. The Rebol 2 driver is quite concise so migrating it to Rebol 3 might be an option.
If you are interested in updating the Rebol 2 one then you will find this tutorial by Graham Chiu very useful:

https://github.com/gchiu/rebol.net/blob/master/docs/Writing_a_Network_Scheme.adoc

@rebolek has also written a Redis protocol which may serve as a useful reference:

https://github.com/rebolek/prot-redis

To the best of my knowledge the most recent Rebol 2 version is here:

http://softinnov.org/rebol/pgsql.shtml

The author of the Rebol 2 PostgresSQL driver is still active in the community (and is now developing the Red language) so he may be able to help with support and suggestions. Come and visit us over in the Stack Overflow Rebol and Red chat room and hopefully we can offer further help.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red